# Put two cells beside one cell

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create a layout like this: [Collection View Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsSV7.png)

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *mutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [mutable addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(250, 399)]];
    [mutable addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(124, 199)]];
    [mutable addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(124, 199)]];
    [mutable addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(375, 199)]];
    [mutable addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(124, 199)]];
    [mutable addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(124, 199)]];
    [mutable addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(124, 199)]];

    array = [mutable copy];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return array.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;

}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [array[indexPath.item] CGSizeValue];
}
```

But the code shows only this: [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuAh5.png)

But the collection view show only one cell beside another. Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you show us the code ? Where is your exact problem ?

Comment: Ok I added the code